# why isn't "execute task" showing up when i right click on the task?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I just re-opened a package that I had been working on in SSIS 2008, and when I right click on one of the tasks, the "execute task" option is not showing up:

[image]

Just a few minutes ago it was showing up (before re-opening it). What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps a little bit more information would be helpful in getting your guidance:

1. "execute task" was showing up without problems
2. i closed to the package, and re-opened as administrator
3. "execute task" disappeared (even when i opened with regular permissions)

Here are the properties of this specific task. Please note that NONE of the tasks have "execute task" when right clicking:

[image]

Comment: The account you created the solution with and the account you opened it with is the same? Both administrator? or 2 different ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that you have opened the individual Package.

The Execute Task command only appears when you have first opened a Project or Solution, then opened your Package.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.. you saved a lot of time for me. I closed and opened the solution and it appeared. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam that'll be $5.99 please. feel free to paypal Mr Honey

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing that kind of issue and the solution was going to `File > Open > Project/Solution...`, selecting my `.sln` file (Visual studio Solution), and that would open my SSIS solution from Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio.

Comment: man that was years ago, i dont even remember what this was about

Comment: @AlexGordon That has happened to me with some of my questions from years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PackageType property and make sure it is `DTSDesigner100` (enum value 5).

If you don't see PackageType in the properties panel, put `DTS:PackageType="5"` in the DTS:Executable section at the top of the .dtsx file.

If the `DTS:PackageType` is 2, you won't have the Execute Task in the right-click menu or all of the icons in the menu bar under the tabs that contains 'Control Flow' and 'Data Flow'.